# How do I recognise a browser tab has closed and close the listener?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm using the following code (Adapted from [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/1dce119eb5200be57a6ff24159b895594d6bd558/Src/Support/GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4/OAuth2/LocalServerCodeReceiver.cs) example) to perform PKCE authorization.

```
 public static async Task<string> ReceiveCodeAsync(string authorisationUrl, string redirectUrl, string state)
        {
            using var listener = new HttpListener();
            listener.Prefixes.Add(redirectUrl);
            try
            {
                listener.Start();

                var process = new Process { StartInfo = { UseShellExecute = true, FileName = authorisationUrl } };
                process.Start();

                // Wait to get the authorization code response.
                var context = await listener.GetContextAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                var coll = context.Request.QueryString;

                // Write a "close" response.
                await using (var writer = new StreamWriter(context.Response.OutputStream))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(ClosePageResponse);
                    writer.Flush();
                }
                context.Response.OutputStream.Close();

                if (coll["state"] != state)
                    throw new SpotifyAuthException("The returned state was invalid");

                return coll["code"];
            }
            finally
            {
                listener.Close();
            }
        }
```

It works fine normally, the browser launches, the user authorises and a code is returned. However, if the user closes the tab instead, the listener is always waiting to `GetContextAsync()`.

I've tried using the process exited event to recognise when the tab has closed, but that triggers as soon as the tab is launched if a browser window is already open.

Is there another way I can release the listener if the user closes the login tab?

Comment: The only real thing you can do is poll the tab ever few seconds to check for life, and if you detect that it is gone, assume the tab is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
    var http = new HttpListener();
    http.Prefixes.Add(<your URI>);
    http.Start();
    
    var result = http.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(ListenerCallback), http);

    bool success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(5000, true);

    if (success == false)
    {
        throw new Exception("Timeout waiting for http request.");
    }

    var context = http.EndGetContext(result);

    private static void ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        //TODO
    }
```